# Swift: copy bytes from array to array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have some performance sensitive code that needs to copy a range of values from one array to another at a specific offset. Can you perform a simple move memory operation in Swift? I've been reading on this all morning but they've made it so incredibly difficult to access memory in Swift I'm not sure if it's even possible (I'm new to Swift obviously).

I did try to use Array.replaceSubrange but it created a big nasty block of code with who knows how many memory copies under the hood getting "array slices" and the function itself is probably slow judging by how Swift is so far. A simple memmove() would slay the problem easily.

An example of what I think is possible.

```
var src: [UInt32] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var dest: [UInt32] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

dest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { destBytes in
    src.withUnsafeBytes { srcBytes in
       // for example copy 4 bytes starting at the address of destBytes[1]
       // from the address of srcBytes[1]
       movemem(&destBytes[1], &srcBytes[1], 4)
    }
}
// dest now should be [0, 2, 3, 0] assuming UInt32 is 2 bytes
```

Comment: Could you please paste your expected result too?

Comment: *"Array.replaceSubrange ... is **probably** slow judging by how Swift is so far"* – can you provide some concrete measurements confirming that hypothesis?

Comment: I edited the question to included the expected result. Really basic memory stuff you'd do in any other language.

Comment: in the best case scenario Array.replaceSubrange would call memmove() eventually. Even before I call the function I had to create a "slice" using the [0...0] syntax and I don't know what that is. It's could be something allocated on the heap and garbage collected later for all I know. Just the fact I need to call .withUnsafeXXX is bad enough for such a trivial operation.

Comment: Well `[0...0]` is `range`. `[0...2]` means from 0th to 2nd.

Comment: Your code snippet has compile time error. I'm using `swift 4.0`

Comment: Just pseudo code. won't compile. :) The point is I have access to "unsafe memory" now so I should be able to copy bytes starting at offsets. Maybe I can just call memmove() from c at this point?

Comment: You're just testing it or you actually want to insert a subrange of an array into another at specific point?

Comment: Yes I want to copy X bytes from an offset into one array to another array.  It looks like you can call memmove from Swift but if I can get the "UnsafeRawPointer" from it.

Comment: Then why don't you use `dest[0] = src[0..2]` like this?

Comment: And AFAIK `UInt32` is of `4 bytes`.

Comment: dest[0] = src[0..2] doesn't appear to be valid Swift and I don't know what that would do if it was (maybe just calls Array.replaceSubrange). The array I need to copy is structs so UInt32 is just an example but yes you're right (on 64 bit systems)

Comment: I'd like to say this question is probably better titled as "how to call memmove in Swift". I just want to call memmove if only I could get the address of array elements from Swift.

Comment: @GenericPtr Oh I just answered and you changed the `theme` of  question to `how to call memmove in Swift`. :|

Comment: Sorry I meant "copy and replace/overwrite" which is essentially what memmove does or Array.replaceSubrange would have done.

Comment: `dest.replaceSubrange(1...2, with: src[1...2])` does exactly what are asking for. Have you **verified** that this is too slow, or are you just speculating?

Comment: Btw, an array slice refers to the original element storage, it does not create a copy of the elements on the heap.

Comment: Because memmove is highly optimized and the lowest level we can get. Why do I want to produce array slices with x...x syntax (what even are those??), copy parameters to the function, and then into Apple's black box which eventually just calls memmove anyways. I'm copying bytes from a bitmap into OpenGL textures in real time so I can't mess around with high-level functions. Memmove is so easy also I don't see any reasons to NOT use it.

Comment: The "slice" is probably something like a CFRange which has to be created and passed to the function. I have no idea how Apple implemented this so I don't want to introduce it into the system. The key point is my code is performance sensitive so I don't care about readability/safety etc... it just needs to be fast.

Comment: I suggest that you use the simple, safe and straightforward `replaceSubrange()`  first and **profile** to check if that part is a significant bottleneck of your program, before you dive into unsafe pointer jugglery. There is a lot of speculation right now: *"replaceSubrange  is probably slow"*, *"It's could be something allocated on the heap and garbage collected"*, *"The "slice" is probably something like a CFRange which has to be created"*, but no concrete measurement.

Comment: I don't need to profile to know memmove() beats any function that eventually calls memmove() anyways. This is an extremely basic memory operation that would be trivial in any other language (one line!) but it's apparently "unsafe" and should be avoided at all costs in Swift. That what computers do, read and write memory.

Comment: Please see my posted answer. Maybe you have some more insights into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming question is for** *needs to copy a range of values from one array to another at a specific offset.*

```
var src: [UInt32] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var dest: [UInt32] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

let rangeOfSrc = [1...2] /// Will get from 1st to 2nd so that 2, 3
dest.insert(contentsOf: rangeOfSrc, at: 2) /// Will insert this range at 2nd position of the dest array
print(dest)
```

> **Output:** [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0]

Would like to refer to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641389-insert) for more detail.

**Edit2: In case you want to replace the range instead of inserting.**

```
dest.replaceSubrange(1...2, with: src[1...2])
print(dest)
```

> **Output:** [0, 2, 3, 0]

**Edit1: `memmove`**

```
memmove(&dest[0], &src[0], 4)
print(dest)
```

> **Output:** [1, 0, 0, 0]

**Edit3**

```
src.withUnsafeBufferPointer {(result) in
     memmove(&dest[0], result.baseAddress, 8)
     print(dest)
}
```

> **Output:** [1, 2, 0, 0]

Comment: Yeah insert is not what I want because it grows the array. I didn't think to try that "pseudo" code I typed but it does compile. :) However something is wrong because MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride returns 4 yet "memmove(&dest[0], &src[0], 4 * 2)" returns dest = [1, 16777216, 0, 0]. Something went wrong and I didn't know you can access memory that like in Swift so who knows what it was addressing.

Comment: If you're thinking that passing `8` in `len` param will get the next object into `dest` array then this is wrong here.

Comment: @GenericPtr See `Edit2` of my answer. It will replace the range instead of inserting. You probably want the same.

Comment: That's not how memmove works. The last param is the number of bytes copied from the src pointer so 8 should be 2 elements of the array and produce [1, 2, 0, 0]. I'm new to Swift but I'm nearly positive you can't just get the address of variables like that and expect to actually get their location of the stack. We're addressing something with that code but it's not the stack probably. We need a withUnsafeXXX call I'm pretty sure.

Comment: But how would that copy it to the just next index? `&dest[0], &src[0]` make sense that `src's 0th` element is being copying into `dest's 0th` index. But how by passing the `len` to `8` copy the src[1] to dest[1]? This is not true.

Comment: one element of the array is 4 bytes (UInt32) so 2 elements is 8 bytes. Memmove copies 8 bytes, which is 2 elements from src[0] to dest[0] which means the first 2 elements of dest have been set (0, 1).  All of this assumes we actually the address of those array elements which I suspect we don't.

Comment: `memmove(&dest[0], ...)` passes the address of a memory location containing the first element to memmove. In practice it *probably* is a pointer to the complete contiguous element storage, but Swift does not guarantee that.

Comment: Yes `&` is the memory address of the element. According to [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer) it should work in `Swift`.

Comment: the address of A memory location, perhaps not THE memory location. :) From the little I know about Swift it's very unlikely that is actually addressing memory on the stack like C would. Try indexing into the array and you'll probably get garbage like we saw in the first comment on this post.

Comment: Yes the address of  where the object is stored somewhere for Computer.  I know that :).

Comment: I mean it may (and probably does) reference a pointer which Swift uses internally. The doc you posted is for raw pointers which you acquire via one of the withUnsafeXXX calls. That's the actually pointer to the real location in memory. Look back at the first comment and see how I got garble reading more than 4 bytes (the size of a pointer) into &dest[0].

Comment: Look at my latest update to my answer. That's getting much closer now and is probably good enough for now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of answering my own question even though I don't think this is the best solution. Not knowing Swift well I would this may be the best we can do but there is a potential memory allocation with the cast to UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating:) for memmove(). There has to be a way to cast that, otherwise inserting that allocation in my code would certainly kill performance.

If anyone knows how to avoid the cast to UnsafeMutableRawPointer please let me know.

```
        var src: [UInt32] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        var dest: [UInt32] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        let elemSize = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride

        dest.withUnsafeBytes { (destBuffer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
            src.withUnsafeBytes { (srcBuffer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in

                // memmove requires UnsafeMutableRawPointer but how do we avoid this allocation?
                // maybe Swift optimizes this somehow but it looks really bad from here
                let destPtr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: destBuffer.baseAddress)
                let destOffset = destPtr! + elemSize
                let srcOffset = srcBuffer.baseAddress! + 0

                // copy 2 elements from src[0] to dest[1]
                memmove(destOffset, srcOffset, elemSize * 2)
            }
        }

        print(dest) // [0, 1, 2, 0]
```

**EDIT 1:** Getting closer now. replaceSubrange() is obviously slower than memmove(), about 6-7x slower in fact. The smaller the byte count the faster replaceSubrange() is by comparison. In a real example you'd only get the arrays bytes once before performing all the memmove() calls so it's even faster than this in practice.

replaceSubrange:  0.750978946685791

memmove:  0.139282941818237

```
func TestMemmove() {
    var src: [UInt32] = Array(repeating: 1, count: 1000)
    var dest: [UInt32] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1000)

    let elemSize = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride
    let testCycles = 100000
    let rows = 200

    var startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0..<testCycles {
        dest.replaceSubrange(1...1+rows, with: src[0...rows])
    }
    var endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("replaceSubrange:  \(endTime - startTime)")

    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0..<testCycles {
        dest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { destBytes in
            src.withUnsafeMutableBytes { srcBytes in
                let destOffset = destBytes.baseAddress! + elemSize
                let srcOffset = srcBytes.baseAddress! + 0
                memmove(destOffset, srcOffset, elemSize * rows)
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("memmove:  \(endTime - startTime)")    
}
```

**EDIT 2:** After all this stupidity just call memmove from c is fastest. Swift will pass pointers to the first element of the array to c function and you can use pointer arithmetic from c to handle the offsets which required .withUnsafeXXX calls in Swift (that probably allocated some classes wrappers).

The conclusion is that Swift is slow so patch out to c with any performance sensitive code.

BlockMove:  0.0957469940185547
replaceSubrange:  1.89903497695923
memmove:  0.136561989784241

```
// from .c file bridged to Swift
void BlockMove (void* dest, int destOffset, const void* src, int srcOffset, size_t count) {
    memmove(dest + destOffset, src + srcOffset, count);
}

func TestMemmove() {
var src: [UInt32] = Array(repeating: 1, count: 1000)
var dest: [UInt32] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1000)

let elemSize = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride
let testCycles = 100000
let rows = 500
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime = 0
var endTime: CFAbsoluteTime = 0

// BlockMove (from c)
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for _ in 0..<testCycles {
    BlockMove(&dest, Int32(elemSize), &src, 0, Int32(elemSize * rows))
}
endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print("BlockMove:  \(endTime - startTime)")

// replaceSubrange
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for _ in 0..<testCycles {
    dest.replaceSubrange(1...1+rows, with: src[0...rows])
}
endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print("replaceSubrange:  \(endTime - startTime)")

// memmove
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for _ in 0..<testCycles {
    dest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { destBytes in
        src.withUnsafeMutableBytes { srcBytes in
            let destOffset = destBytes.baseAddress! + elemSize
            let srcOffset = srcBytes.baseAddress! + 0
            memmove(destOffset, srcOffset, elemSize * rows)
        }
    }
}
endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print("memmove:  \(endTime - startTime)")
```

}

Comment: `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating:)`  does *not* allocate memory. However, you can get rid of that conversion by using `dest.withUnsafeMutableBytes`, that gives you a *mutable* buffer pointer in the closure.

Comment: You don't need to get `destBuffer` and this calculation, please check `Edit3` in my answer.